# Set theory exercise involving union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A\subseteq B$ iff $A\cup B = B$

Attempted proof - Suppose $A\subseteq B$ and $x\in A\cup B$ then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$ or both. If $x\in A$ then by hypothesis $x\in B$ as well since $A\subseteq B$, same applies for if $x\in B$. Then this implies that $A\cup B\subseteq B$.

I have no idea where to go from here. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have proved that "$A \subseteq B$ and $x \in A \cup B$ implies $x \in B$". You still need to prove that "$A \subseteq B$ and $x \in B$ implies $x \in A \cup B$" (which will complete the first direction of the equivalence), and then "$A \cup B = B$ implies $A \subseteq B$" (which is the other direction).

To reiterate your first direction:

> If $A \subseteq B$, we show that $A \cup B = B$. It is enough in fact to show that $A \cup B \subseteq B$, because $B \subseteq A \cup B$ is always true.
>
> So suppose $x \in A \cup B$; we need to show that $x \in B$. Since $x \in A \cup B$, we have either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$.
>
> - If $x \in B$, we are immediately done.
> - If $x \in A$, then by the hypothesis that $A \subseteq B$, we have $x \in B$, so we are done again.

By this point we have proved that $A \subseteq B$ implies $A \cup B = B$.

For the converse, suppose $A \not \subseteq B$.
Then there is $x \in A$ which is not in $B$.
But then $x \in A \cup B$, and $x \not \in B$, so it is not the case that $A \cup B = B$: we have exhibited something which is in one but not the other.

Comment: Not really sure if I understand what you are saying

Comment: Anything in particular?

Comment: Are you saying that I shown that if $x\in A$ then by hypothese $x\in B$ since $A\subseteq B$ so $x\in A\cup B$. Now I need to show if $x\in B$ we have $x\in A\cup B$?

Comment: @Wolfy Yes, under the assumption that $A \subseteq B$. Once you've done that, you've shown "$A \subseteq B \Rightarrow A \cup B = B$", which is the first direction of the equivalence. (What you showed in your original answer was "$A \subseteq B \Rightarrow A \cup B \subseteq B$".)

Comment: Ok but if $x\in B$ and $B\supseteq A$ doesn't that imply $x\in A$?

Comment: @Wolfy Yes. But you need to say so. (Well, you don't really need to say so; most mathematicians will be able to do that step themselves. But this is an elementary-set-theory question, so I assumed you wanted every step proved rather than just asserted.)

Comment: Yes, since I am really rusty with this stuff could you just provide a full proof?

Comment: @Wolfy Done in an edit.

Comment: I still don't really get how $A\subseteq B$ implies $A\cup B = B$

Comment: Also, I have no idea how your converse is suppose to prove

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40275/discussion-between-patrick-stevens-and-wolfy).

Comment: Ok, I get it now but I don't really understand your converse argument

Answer (score 0):

Implication is obvious. For the converse, let $x\in A$. Since $A\cup B=B$, then $x\in B$. Finish !

Comment: I think "It's obvious" is not really a suitable answer to an elementary-set-theory question.

Comment: I have no doubt it is obvious but it not obvious for me at the moment. So for your suggestion on the converse I say: suppose $A\cup B = B$ and $x\in A$. Then $x\in B$ by hypotheses?

Comment: You want to show that $A\subset B$. In other word, you take an $x\in A$, and you want to show that $x\in B$. So, let $x\in A$. By hypothesis, $A\cup B=B$. Since $x\in A$, then $x\in A\cup B=B$, and thus $x\in B$, what prove the claim. For the implication, If $A\subset B$, then, if $x\in A$, then $x\in B$. In other word, if $x\in A$, then $x\in B$, and if $x\in B$, then $x\in B$. Therefore, if $x\in A\cup B$, then $x\in B$. Therefore, $(A\cup B)\subset B$. For $B\subset (A\cup B)$, I hope it's clear !